# Highcharts. Browser compatibility issues

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm currently working on a website that uses Highcharts to display
some data. I've been testing the different options, retrieving data
from the server, etc and everything works perfect, but ONLY on chrome.

When testing it on firefox, I can see where the chart is supposed to
be. I can see the border, title, print/export buttons (all of this
generated by the plugin itself), but not the data. I used firebug to
check if it was retrieving the data correctly from the server and
everything seems to be fine.

On IE6 gets even worse, becouse I can't even see the border, title, etc..

I read somewhere that Highcharts had an issue with line charts and
jquery 1.7, but I tried with different types of charts and changed my
jquery version to 1.8. It always works on chrome, but doesn't on
firefox/IE6

I'm not pasting any code becouse I honestly have no idea where the
problem is and i'm hoping i'ts just a bug that I can easily solve..
Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I checked out jsFiddle but I couldn't figure how to make it work without the server side without changing some stuff. Here's some of the code. Hope it can be helpful:

```
HTML

<html class="gecko  win" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" xml:lang="en" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
    <title>Portal de Conciliacion SMS Prepago</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Plantilla/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="Highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="Highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">@import "DataTables/media/css/demo_table.css";</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Plantilla/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="Plantilla/style.ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="Plantilla/style.ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->   
</head>
    <body>
        <div style="overflow: hidden">  
            <div id="diferencia" style="width: 48%; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
            <br>
            <br>        
            <div id="ttdm" style="float: left; width: 48%; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>        
            <div id="rtbs" style="float: right; width: 48%; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Im also usign the datatables plugin to show the data in the page. I left that part of the code out but kept the includes in case it might have something to do)

```
JS

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

$(function () {

    var fecha = getUrlVars()["fecha"];
    if (fecha) {
        console.log(fecha);
    }
    else {
        fecha = "";
        console.log("NO!!!");
    }

    var chart_diferencia;
    var chart_ttdm;
    var chart_rtbs;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var options_diff = {

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'diferencia',
                borderColor: '#000000',
                borderWidth: 2,
                margin: [30, 30, 30, 30],
                type: 'area'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Diferencia (TTDM vs RTBS)'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval: 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                tickWidth: 5,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e/%m', this.value);
                    }
                }           
            },

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    x: -12,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000, 0) + 'K';
                    }
                },
                showFirstLabel: false,
            }],

            legend: {
                enabled: false,
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                crosshairs: true,               
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Diferencia',
                color: '#FF8C00',
                lineWidth: 2,
                marker: {
                    radius: 3
                }
            }]
        };

        var options_ttdm = {

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'ttdm',
                borderColor: '#000000',
                borderWidth: 2,
                margin: [30, 30, 30, 30],
                type: 'area'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'TTDM (cursado)'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval: 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                tickWidth: 5,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e/%m', this.value);
                    }
                }           
            },

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    x: -12,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000000, 0) + 'M';
                    }
                },
                showFirstLabel: false,
            }],

            legend: {
                enabled: false,
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                crosshairs: true,               
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'TTDM',
                lineWidth: 2,
                marker: {
                    radius: 3
                }
            }]
        };

        var options_rtbs = {

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'rtbs',
                borderColor: '#000000',
                borderWidth: 2,
                margin: [30, 30, 30, 30],
                type: 'area'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'RTBS (facturado)'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval: 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                tickWidth: 5,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e/%m', this.value);
                    }
                }           
            },

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    x: -12,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000000, 0) + 'M';
                    }
                },
                showFirstLabel: false,
            }],

            legend: {
                enabled: false,
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                crosshairs: true,               
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'RTBS',
                color: '#8B0000',
                lineWidth: 2,
                marker: {
                    radius: 3
                }
            }]
        };


        // Load data asynchronously using jQuery. On success, add the data
        // to the options and initiate the chart.
        // This data is obtained by exporting a GA custom report to TSV.
        // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
        jQuery.get('Solicitudes/concil_TTDMvsRTBS.php', null, function(tsv, state, xhr) {
            var lines = [],
                listen = false,
                date,

                // set up the two data series
                diferencia = [],
                ttdm = [],
                rtbs = [];

            // inconsistency
            if (typeof tsv !== 'string') {
                tsv = xhr.responseText;
            }

            // split the data return into lines and parse them
            tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
            jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {



                listen = true;
                //console.log(line);

                // all data lines start with a double quote
                if (line != "") {


                    line = line.split(',');

                    //console.log(line);



                    date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');

                    diferencia.push([
                        date,
                        parseInt(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                    ]);
                    ttdm.push([
                        date,
                        parseInt(line[2].replace(',', ''), 10)
                    ]);
                    rtbs.push([
                        date,
                        parseInt(line[3].replace(',', ''), 10)
                    ]);
                }
            });

            //console.log(allVisits);
            diferencia.reverse();
            ttdm.reverse();
            rtbs.reverse();


            options_diff.series[0].data = diferencia;
            options_ttdm.series[0].data = ttdm;
            options_rtbs.series[0].data = rtbs;
            //options.series[1].data = newVisitors;

            //console.log(allVisits);
            //console.log(newVisitors);


            Highcharts.setOptions({ 
                lang: { 
                    weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado']
                } 
            }); 
            Highcharts.setOptions({ 
                lang: { 
                    months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']
                } 
            }); 
            chart_diferencia = new Highcharts.Chart(options_diff);
            chart_ttdm = new Highcharts.Chart(options_ttdm);
            chart_rtbs = new Highcharts.Chart(options_rtbs);

            console.log("LISTO!");
        });

        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sScrollY": "200px",
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bAutoWidth": true
        });
    });

});
```

It's kind of long becouse I set up the options for three different graphics. The get part is a little bit messy becouse I got there by modifiying the example that comes with the plugin, but I have checked on both debbuging consoles (firebug and chrome) and the data is beign received exactly the same on both.

I read on highcharts support forum that stray commas in the charts options could be the reason it doesn't work on IE6, gotta check tomorrow at work. But as i mentioned earlier, on firefox i can see the background, title, print/export buttons, but none of the data..

The highchart version is 2.2.5. I dowloaded the 2.3 but havent tried it yet. First thing tomorrow morning.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a fiddle on jsFiddle.net? You can paste all your code into there and get a sandbox working for anyone to mess around with.

Comment: I've made perfectly workable Highcharts for IE7 > and every other browser. Every serious developer has stopped supporting IE6 by now, you should consider doing so too (howcome you still have it installed??). And like Wahl said; post some of your code to us :))

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I edited the post and added some code

Comment: @OptimusCrime believe it or not a lot of the pcs where I work have XP installed and a lot people use the default browser

Comment: @Alex: Create a demo using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @HardikMishra i dont know how to simmulate the server side. I use jquery's $get to retrieve the results, and I cant  find any examples on how to do that in jsfiddle

Comment: use/modify/update this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/j4ZYB/ it has ajax and highcharts

Comment: btw jQuery 1.8 isn't exactly supported by Highcharts yet, stick to an earlier version

Comment: @OptimusCrime it appears you do not do a lot of work with government agencies. The IT departments for states are very much behind the times. So, whatever came with the PC is what the users have to work with. No installing 3rd party browsers etc. Not the best environment but it is reality for some of us developers.